# Setting var not working in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

I need to display different html depending on user variable. Everything is working correctly when I am debugging the code. But normally there are no changes when user is not null:

```
<div id="main-menu">
    <c:set var="logText" value="Log in"/>
    <c:set var="logId" value="login-item"/>
    <c:if test="${user != null}">
        <c:set var="logText" value="Log out"/>
        <c:set var="logId" value="logout-item"/>
    </c:if>
    <a href="">About</a> <span id="<c:out value="${logId}" />"><c:out value="${logText}" /></span>
</div>
```

Can you help me, why if-statement not working?

Comment: use `ne`instead of `!=`

Comment: use ${not empty user} that will check for null as well as empty string

Comment: @Philipp: they are equivalent.

Comment: @AurA: good one, but note that it works only if `${user}` is a `String` for some unclear reason (normally, this is a whole `User` javabean instance with all user-related properties such as firstname, birthdate, email, etc on it).

Comment: @BalusC yes that is true I assumed it be string because he did not access anything like user.something... in case it is an object then != or ne or not empty all will act same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<c:if test="${not empty user}">
```

Are you sure that user is not null? Try to print out user's value.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, there was a redirect after which user was becoming null